# Имя функции gtk_show_about_dialog() в lgi

Tags: lua, gtk

Пробую рисовать диалог "`О программе`" в lgi, однако

```
Gtk.AboutDialog.show == Gtk.Widget.show
```

Как сказано в руководстве по Gtk, нужна функция `gtk_show_about_dialog()` в `C`. Но как её вызвать из `lgi`?

**UPD**: с вызовом *большинства* функций lgi у меня проблем нет. Речь именно о `gtk_show_about_dialog()`.

Comment: не все функции С можно вызвать, но есть библиотеки, которые позволяют это делать, но они не очень надежны. вы хотите знать как функции С вызываются (примеры там... ) или найти gtk_show_about_dialog() функцию для вас?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В демках `lgi` есть [пример](https://github.com/pavouk/lgi/blob/master/samples/gtkhello.lua#L37), как создавать диалог "О программе":

```
-- About button in toolbar and its handling.
local about_button =  Gtk.ToolButton { stock_id = 'gtk-about' }
function about_button:on_clicked()
   local dlg = Gtk.AboutDialog {
      program_name = 'LGI Demo',
      title = 'About...',
      name = 'LGI Hello',
      copyright = '(C) Copyright 2010, 2011 Pavel Holejšovský',
      authors = { 'Adrian Perez de Castro', 'Pavel Holejšovský', },
   }
   if tonumber(Gtk._version) >= 3 then
      dlg.license_type = Gtk.License.MIT_X11
   end
   dlg:run()
   dlg:hide()
end
toolbar:insert(about_button, -1)
```

Вызывать же функцию `gtk_show_about_dialog()` напрямую, нет необходимости (если её вообще возможно вызвать, в рамках `lgi`).

Comment: Не согласен с вами. В документации по gtk+ четко сказано: рекомендуется использовать gtk_show_about_dialog, но можно и традиционным run. Так что неправильный ответ (как мне кажется).

Comment: Вот тут https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAboutDialog.html#gtk-show-about-dialog про эту функцию сказано, что она сделана для удобства (чтобы за один вызов и установить все свойства и показать диалог). Про "рекомендовано" там не сказано.

Comment: @val заглянув в сорцы `gtk` могу сказать, что внутри себя эта функция ничего магического не делает, а просто является обёрткой над стандартным интерфейсом (т.е. вызывает внутри себя конструктор, инициализацию полей и показ окна). Она может быть полезна для тех, кто использует `gtk` из Си, но в `lua` и так всё достаточно удобно.

Comment: Ок, возможно ошибся. Читал документацию по собственно диалогу.